# KDevelop debugging warning: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, kdevelop

A while ago I changed my personal operating system to linux and my development enviroment to KDevelop.

However debugging c++ projects is still not working as it should.
My KDevelop version is 4.2.2 (I installed it through package management)

Every time I hit the "debug button" the application is starting with the console message 
`warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted` and debugging functionality is not available.

Any ideas welcome.

(If you need additional information don't hesitate to ask)

Comment: Just a *nitpick* Googling that warning gives 6k hits actually.

Comment: I googled that warning but I wasn't able to fix it- this is why I wrote this post.

Comment: People still use KDevelop?  I haven't touched that in like 10 years...

Comment: Does `gdb` work as expected from the command line?

Comment: I remember trying it once and it was complaining I didnt have a Gameboy Advance :) Or something like that.

Comment: I'm not familar with gdb I get: Reading symbols from /home/tobias/Dev/Projects/RCMeta/build/RCMetaTest/RCMetaTest...(no debugging symbols found)...done.

Comment: This error also occurs in Code::Blocks and Netbeans

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I also had this problem, but I use gdb in KDevelop sparsely enough that hadn't bothered me yet. Here's my log of trying to fix it:

Grepping through the GDB 7.3.1 source code reveals that this message is printed when GDB tries to set its master TTY to a newly-created pseudo-tty (see gdb/inflow.c, lines 683-740). In particular, a call to ioctl with request TIOCSCTTY fails with a permissions error.

With this in mind, I took a look at the Linux kernel source code to see what could cause a failure. A bit of searching shows that it will eventually degenerate into a call to  tiocsctty(). The comment from tiocsctty that is important here:

```
/*
 * The process must be a session leader and
 * not have a controlling tty already.
 */
```

Since the only other reason it can fail with EPERM is if the tty that GDB creates is actually a controlling tty for *another* process (which seems highly unlikely), I thought it reasonable to assume that GDB is not a session leader. Fair enough, it's launched by KDevelop after all!

So: I tried *not* launching the GDB session in an external terminal, and it works. Problem narrowed down.

Originally, the external terminal line was set to `konsole --noclose --workdir %workdir -e %exe`. Changing this to `terminator -e %exe` made a slight difference: KDevelop warned me that

```
GDB cannot use the tty* or pty* devices.
Check the settings on /dev/tty* and /dev/pty*
As root you may need to "chmod ug+rw" tty* and pty* devices and/or add the user to the tty group using "usermod -G tty username".
```

I checked my permissions; my user was part of the tty group and all relevant files were readable and writable.

Grepping through the KDevelop source code reveals how KDevelop actually sets up the terminal. It runs the shell script

```
tty > FIFO_PATH ; trap "" INT QUIT TSTP ; exec<&-; exec>&-; while :; do sleep 3600;done
```

and then sets up GDB to use the terminal device it reads from FIFO_PATH. (My name, by the way, not the one that KDevelop uses.) The problem (as best I can tell) is that gdb is not launched as a child of the shell script, and thus cannot use it as its main tty.

I'm not feeling up to patching KDevelop to make this work properly as of yet (or finding what actually caused this to stop working in the first place . . .), so the best I can suggest at the moment is to simply not use an external terminal for debugging purposes.

Good luck! I'll update if I find anything useful.

Comment: and you only got +54 for your reply?! dude that goes on my twitter straight away! What a nice/perfect feedback

Comment: unfortunately not using an external terminal is not an option for people debugging an ncurses app

Answer (score 1):

As Arthur Zennig said, for more information, you need to do something

1. Firstly, you need to create the Terminal profile

[image]

2. Secondly, open Launch Configurations, fill info such as the image below

[image]

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In case you got the error:

> "Can't receive konsole tty/pty. Check that konsole is actually a
>   terminal and that it accepts these arguments"

RUN > CONFIGURE LAUCHERS > (See picture below. My project name was "loops") 
What worked for me was to uncheck checkbox "Use External Terminal". Found the in the "Compiled Binaries" Tab.

[image: RUN > Configure Laucher]